# Understanding metaclasses in Python

Tags: python, metaclass

I am trying to get my head around metaclass but i still can't really get the concept of it.

For all i know:

Any class is itself an instance of type "type" - therefore "calling" a class just calls the method `__call__` on its class - which happens to be type's `__call__`. The effect of `type.__call__` is exactly: on code like:

class A:
    pass
b = A()

The sequence of steps i know here is:

1.`type.__call__` receives the class A itself as its first parameter.

2. It calls the `A.__new__` - in pseudocode we could write `instance = A.__new__(cls)` as what runs.

3.That returns an instance of the "A" class

4.Then it calls `__init__` on the instance(`instance.__init__()`)
...and returns that instance return instance

But now consider the below code:

```
class MetaOne(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, supers, classdict):
        print('In MetaOne.new:', meta, classname, supers, classdict, sep='\n...')
        return type.__new__(meta, classname, supers, classdict)

class Eggs:
    pass

print('making class')

class Spam(Eggs, metaclass=MetaOne): 
    data = 1 
    def meth(self, arg): 
        return self.data + arg

print('making instance')
X = Spam()
print('data:', X.data, X.meth(2))
```

The output from this script is as follows:

```
making class
In MetaOne.new:
...<class '__main__.MetaOne'>
...Spam
...(<class '__main__.Eggs'>,)
...{'__qualname__': 'Spam', '__module__': '__main__', 'meth': <function Spam.met
h at 0x00000000010C1D08>, 'data': 1}
making instance
data: 1 3
```

So as per my understanding this is the sequence of steps:

1. Since Spam is an instance of MetaOne, calling `X = Spam()` would try to call the `__call__` method of MetaOne class which is not there .
2. Since MetaOne inherits from type it would call the `__call__` method of type class with `Spam` as the first argument.

After that the call lands up in the `__new__` method of MetaOne class but it should contain `Spam` as the first param.

From where does `meta` argument of MetaOne class come into picture.

Please help me in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

> Since Spam is an instance of MetaOne, calling X = Spam() would try to
>   call the `__call__` method of MetaOne class which is not there .

That is the soruce of your confusion - the `__call__` (or `__new__` and `__init__`) of the metaclass is *not* called when you create ordinary instances of the class.

Also, since there is no `__call__` method for `MetaOne`, the usual inheritance rules apply: the `__call__` method on MetaOne's superclass is used (and it is `type.__call__`)

The metaclass' `__new__` and `__init__` methods are invoked when the class body itself is executed (as you can see in your example, the "print" in the metaclass' `__new__` shows up before the "making instance" text).

When creating an instance of `Span` itself, the metaclass methods `__new__`  and `__init__` are not called - the metaclass  `__call__` is called - and it is that that executes the class's(Span's) `__new__` and `__init__`. In other words: the metaclass `__call__` is responsible for calling the "ordinary" class's `__new__` and `__init__`.

> Since MetaOne inherits from type it would call the **call** method of
>   type class with Spam as the first argument.

And it does, but you made no print statements to "view" this happening:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace):
        print("At meta __new__")
        return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)   
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwd):
        print ("at meta __call__")
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwd)

def Egg(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def __new__(cls):
        print("at class __new__")
```

If I paste this at the ineractive console, at this point it prints:

```
At meta __new__
```

Then, going on the interactive session:

```
In [4]: fried = Egg()
at meta __call__
at class __new__
```

And the extra mind-twisting thing is that: "type is type's own metaclass": meaning that `type`'s `__call__` is also responsible for running the `__new__` and `__init__`  methods on the metaclass itself, when a new (non-meta) class body is executed.