# Singleton class using metaclasses

Tags: python, singleton

Below is the well known code for creating a singleton metaclass:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            cls.x = 5
        return cls._instances[cls]


class MyClass(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass

m = MyClass()
v = MyClass()
print (m.x)
m.x = 420
print (v.x)
```

My question is why do we need to use the **call** function of type class again to  initialize the class? Why can't we call the init method to do that like normal class initialization. Something like this :

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = cls(*args, **kwargs)
            cls.x = 5
        return cls._instances[cls]


class MyClass(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass

m = MyClass()
v = MyClass()
print (m.x)
m.x = 420
print (v.x)
```

This is getting into an infinite loop anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because trying to creating an instance of a class by just calling it as you do in the line `cls._instances[cls] = cls(*args, **kwargs)` just by itself calls the metaclass `__call__` which is  the exact method where you attempt the call, [as is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44197238/108205).

Now, if one thing, you should not really be using metaclasses just for creating singletons.

The Metaclass mechanism in Python is complicated - the problem you've hit on this question shows you are grasping now how simple inheritance and call to methods on super-classes work - and metaclasses are an order of magnitude more complicated than that.

And, beyond been complicated, classes with a custom metaclass can't be ordinarily combined with other classes that feature custom metaclasses, so the general rule is keeping their usage to a minimum anyway.

## How to create a singleton class:

But for creatign a singleton, you can just place all your checks in the class ordinary `__new__` method. No need to feedle with metaclasses - just plain class inheritance:

```
_instances = {}

class Singleton(object):

   def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
      if not cls in _instances:
          instance = super().__new__(cls)
          _instances[cls] = instance

      return _instances[cls]
```

And just inherit your singleton classes from this one.

Comment: One thing to be careful about when using `__new__()` to implement the singleton pattern is that `__init__()` will always be called on the instance that gets returned, even if it's already previously been initialized.  Using a metaclass lets you control if/when `__init__()` gets called.  So even though metaclasses are more complicated and do have the downsides mentioned here, I think they're the only option if there's any possibility of subclasses implementing `__init__()`.

Comment: "metaclasses" are __far__ from the only option for singletons. People have a recipe, and that is it. It is easy to circunvent a repeated call to `__init__`, the easier being: do not write an `__init__`, and put all code in `__new__`.

Comment: Still, the simplest way to do a singleton in Python is simply: to create the needed instance as a module variable, and import _that_ instance where its needed instead of importing the class. Marking the class itself as private with a "_" prefix is optional.