# Instance sharing across classes

Tags: python, java, instance

I have this python script which has a listener class and a main class.  A serial stream is created in the main class and a listener instance is created in the main class.  The whole purpose of the listener is to send a message on the serial port when a listened property has changed.  The problem is that the listener doesn't have access to the output stream created in the main class.  The listener does an abrupt return when trying to execute the *outputStream.write* statement  How can I give the listener access to the output stream?

```
import purejavacomm
import java.beansSensorListener

class MyListener(java.beans.PropertyChangeListener):
  def propertyChange(self, event):
    if (< some property has changed >) :
        self.outputStream.write(message) # send notice on serial port
    return


class MainClass(jmri.jmrit.automat.AbstractAutomaton) :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.portID = purejavacomm.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM3")
        self.port = self.portID.open("SerialCom", 50)
        self.outputStream = self.port.getOutputStream()
        return

    def init(self) :
        myListener = MyListener()
        deviceList = devices.getNamedBeanSet()

        for device in deviceList :
            device.addPropertyChangeListener(myListener)
        return

a = MainClass()
a.start();
```

Comment: The same way it woudl always work, provide it as an attribute in `MyListener`, or as an argument to the appropriate method, or as a global variable...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that really `MyListener` should either have a stream passed into the constructor or the callback (using `lambda` expression).

First, which is probably the cleanest way, would look like this:

```
def init(self) :
        myListener = MyListener(self.outputStream)
```

Second version: `device.addPropertyChangeListener(lambda x: myListener(x, self.outputStream))` Both need changes in the `MyListener` class to either constructor, or definition of `propertyChange`.

If you are set of sharing an instance of here are two options.

If you can modify arguments to `MyListener` constructor you pass in instance of `MainClass` to it:

```
def init(self) :
        myListener = MyListener(self)
```

If not, a little bit more hacky way of doing this is by making `MainClass` a singelton (see [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198824/singleton-class-using-metaclasses)), and then calling it's constructor within `MyListener`

Comment: Thanks.  This is what worked: I added this constructor: 
```    def __init__(self, outStream) :
        self.outputStream = outStream
        return
```
And passed the stream to it like this:
```        turnoutListener = TurnoutListener(self.outputStream)
```
And it now works as desired.